# ngif not working with $scope variable angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm very new to programming and have been struggling with this issue all day.

I am trying to get some text to display based on wether the result of the variable 'buttons.buttonState' is 0 or 1. When I use {{buttons.buttonState}} outside of the ngif it returns the result, so I know it does actually contain the variable.

```html
<script>
    var fetch = angular.module('myapp', []);

    fetch.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'dbqueries/startbuttonquery.php'
        }).then(function(response) {
        // Store response data
        $scope.buttons= response.data[0];
        console.log($scope.buttons)
        });
    }]);

</script>
```

```html
<body ng-app='myapp'>
<div ng-controller="userCtrl">
        <div>{{buttons.buttonState}} this returns the value '1'</div>
        <div *ngif="buttons.buttonState==='1'">on</div>

        <div *ngif="buttons.buttonState==='0'">off</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you are using angular 1, you should change ur *ngIf to ng-if

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using angular 1, You should change *ngIf to ng-if.

```
<body ng-app='myapp'>
<div ng-controller="userCtrl">
        <div>{{buttons.buttonState}} this returns the value '1'</div>
        <div ng-if="buttons.buttonState==='1'">on</div>

        <div ng-if="buttons.buttonState==='0'">off</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In angularjs `*ngif` is used as `ng-if`

```
<div ng-if="buttons.buttonState==='1'">on</div>

<div ng-if="buttons.buttonState==='0'">off</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With angularjs syntax it should be ng-if, Replace *ngIf with ng-if

```
<div ng-if="buttons.buttonState==='1'">on</div>
```